# The div with an id 'notes' doesn't display the default note in the javascript codes. How to display it by default?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

1. The default text should be displayed inside the div with an id
   'notes'.
2. The Javascript code for a button to show the notes is indcluded.
3. There are conditions for the updated note and default text to be displayed.
4. The default text portion which should be displayed before updating a not is given.
5. However the default text is not displayed. I didn't find any error. How to do it?

   ```
   <hr>
   <h1>Your Notes:</h1>
   <hr>
   <!-- container-fluid use up all the available spaces -->
   <div id="notes" class="row container-fluid"></div>

   function show_notes() {
       let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
       if (notes == null) {
          notesObj = [];
       }
       else {
           notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
       }
       let html = "";
       notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
           //using backtick
           html += ` 
               <div class="noteCard my-2 mx-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
                       <div class="card-body">
                           <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
                           <p class="card-text">${element}</p>
                           <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
                       </div>
                   </div>`;              
       });           
       let notes_element = document.getElementById("notes");
               if (notesObj.length != 0) {
                   notes_element.innerHTML = html;
                   //console.log("Add notes success!")
               }
               else {//default note
                   notes_element.innerHTML = `No note added. Use "Add Note" button to add a note.`;
                   //console.log('Notes not added!');
               }
           }
   ```

Comment: It seems that the default note needs to be in `localStorage`. Have you checked to make sure it is?

Comment: Actually, the localStorage stores only the notes added not the default note.

Comment: The default text is within the backticks. Is that creating a problem?

Comment: I've tested your code and as long as you declare `notesObj`  and call your `show_notes` function, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If `notesObj` is initialized as an empty array, your `forEach()` will not execute and add the default note HTML.

```js
const test = [];

test.forEach(() => console.log("won't log"));
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your views and solutions. Actually, I was mistaken. The function show_notes() was to call before/outside the .addEventListener and within/at the end of the .addEventListener function.